# Bad behavior of Manipulate with a Greek variable inside

Tags: manipulate

I'm getting bad behavior from `Manipulate` in *Mathematica* 10.4.1. A very basic demonstration:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a*η^2 - η^3 + η^4, {η, -2, 2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {Style["η", 16], Style["F", 16, Italic]}, 
    AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03]], 
  {{a, 0.5}, -1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled", SaveDefinitions -> True}
 ]
```

When the above code is evaluated, it causes a hang-up for some time and then brings up a dialog asking me to choose between aborting or waiting further.  This repeats many times. Funny thing is that if I replace `η` by `x`, the demonstration behaves as expected.

My system is Win. 7.

Comment: It runs well with MMA10.4.1 in linux. But I also get that abort or wait message several times in different occasions.

Comment: Disable "Show Suggestions Bar after last output" and run `Manipulate` again. This works fine on Windows 10 (64 bit) and Mathematica 10.4.1

Comment: @rewi  Thank you, it works. Do you know, how does it related to the Greek letter  `η`?.

Comment: No problem when I run your code with V10.4.1 under OS X 10.10.2. I have the suggestion bar enabled.

Comment: A side issue. I don't understand why you are giving the `SaveDefinitions` option in a control specification.

Comment: @m_goldberg This is not related to the problem of strange behavior. Sorry about that. I simply took the code that I prepared for a lecture after tomorrow, plainly as it was. Very unexpectedly the code refused to work properly, while hundreds of such codes worked properly in the past.

Comment: I agree my query about `SaveDefinitions` is unrelated to your basic problem. That's why I prefixed it with "[a] side issue". I am curious about the usage. I have never seen it before.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Excuse me, I did not understand. You are curious about the usage of what? Are you speaking about `SaveDefinitions`, or about something else?

Comment: About `SaveDefinitions` appearing in `{{a, 0.5}, -1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled", SaveDefinitions -> True}` which is a control specification. This is an undocumented use as far as I know.

Comment: @ m_goldberg Or, no, this is a mistake, it must be outside of the curly braces.